# The placeholder image for community promotion ads doesn't reflect the new sidebar width

Tags: bug, status-deferred, community-promotion-ads

I was checking out the [community promotion ads meta thread](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/community-promotion-ads-2016) for Game Development. For these threads, the answer textbox is pre-filled with some placeholder structure for convenience.

The placeholder image linked in the pre-filled text still has the old 220x250 ad dimensions (the URL of the actual image in the pre-filled text is https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/ad-placeholder.png).

[image]

Is this a CDN caching issue on my end or did these pre-filled templates slip under the radar in the sidebar transition?

Comment: Even worse, it fails to recognize that placeholder is a single word!

Comment: I've retagged this as status-deferred, since we're not sure how we're going to proceed with the community ads program right now. See the announcement [The future of Community Promotion, Open Source, and Hot Network Questions Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/335251) and the latest comments on it for details.