# Community Ads questions on newly 'graduated' sites don't show template in answer box

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, community-promotion-ads, full-sites

JNat just posted a couple of [2020 Community Ads questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344573/295232) across the network. I noticed that in some cases, the answer box is already filled with the template (see the screenshot below):

- [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394409/4751173)
- [Ask Different](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3716/121968)

but in other cases, it is not:

- [Chess](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/709/7297)
- [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1849/12315)

The template seems to be missing for the [29 sites which lost their beta label last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/295232) because of their age.

[image]

Comment: [Was already aware](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2308/community-promotion-ads-2020?noredirect=1#comment6241_2308) and poked someone to look into it :)

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like having a design is necessarily the differentiating factor: [Quantitative Finance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344646/208518) appears to show the template, and it doesn't have a design. I assume (still looking) that it's related to [the 29 "beta" labels that were removed last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/208518).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like we'd forgotten to flip a switch when we got rid of those 29 labels. Adam just flipped it, so it should now show the template as expected.

Comment: Also, the placeholder size and shape are wrong -- they're from the previous dimensions, which are now something like four or five years old? I'm not sure whether this is worth a specific request. It's not terrible, but it's also (presumably) not a hard thing to fix.

Comment: You mean the guidance under Image Requirements?

Comment: I mean [this image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/ad-placeholder.png), which appears pre-filled whenever I add an answer ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXkMI.png)). The guidance under Image Requirements specifies a 300x250 size and aspect ratio, which changed from 220x250 in 2016. The placeholder image has the 2015-and-earlier aspect ratio.

Comment: Gotcha: a separate post for that would be better, if you would...? :)

Comment: `@`JNat [Done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273347). (By someone else, four years ago. No sense in posting a duplicate, I don't think.)