# The future of Community Promotion, Open Source, and Hot Network Questions Ads

Tags: discussion, advertising, announcements, community-promotion-ads

**September update:** The ads are now live! As a way to try to address some of the concerns about the voting period being too short, *we're running the selected ads that score 6 or more, or any ads scoring 4 or more with no downvotes.* You can see the full list of selected ads by running [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1443449/eligible-community-ads-for-2021) (thanks to [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel) and [Slate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1037447/slate) for the help with it). From the 34 sites selected for the trial, 30 sites had at least one ad proposal, and 24 have at least one ad making it through the score threshold to be displayed; a total of 119 ads were selected, and [Code Golf & Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) was the site with the most ads selected, with 19 selected proposals.

From now 'til the end of the year we'll monitor the ads' performance, as well as any reports we get about any of these. If you see something that looks broken or have questions please post those in separate questions using [community-promotion-ads](/questions/tagged/community-promotion-ads) and we'll have a look. Otherwise, stay tuned for updates on next steps in Q1 2022!

---

**June update:** The ad collection posts on all of the sites listed below for the trial period have been posted. Submissions and voting will be open through August 2nd. Thank you for all the feedback — I tried to address most of it, and hope to be able to address some of the outstanding concerns (particularly surrounding ad rotation, etc.) after the trial is over.

---

It's now May, and if Community Promotion or Open Source Ads are something you care about, you may have noticed that there hasn't been a 2021 refresh yet. In case you missed [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362656/208518), please check it out for some details about why the refresh was pushed back, and why a project around the rethinking of that initiative made its way into [our roadmap for Q2 2021](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/23/the-loop-our-community-public-platform-roadmap-for-q2-2021/).

Here I'll focus mostly on the format for a new initiative that'll be broader so it can encompass the goals the Community Promotion and Open Source Ads initiatives tackled, along with a replacement for the Hot Network Questions Ads, and even some other types of ads that Nicolas has experimented with in the International SOs (like [this](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8353/23291), or ads that link to Meta posts like [this](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7020/181239)). That means your communities can get three different types of ads for the price of one... which, by the way, is *for free!* ;)

### The Goals

Some of the goals of this initiative you may already be familiar with, since we're iterating on the existing Community Promotion and Open Source Ads initiatives. To put it simply, Stack Overflow's variant of Community Promotion Ads focuses on highlighting open source projects, whereas the rest of the network allows for promotion of basically anything that each specific community might find interesting or important.

In addition to that slight variation, we're introducing a new additional goal that applies to all the sites. This is the bit that comes in to replace the now-retired Hot Network Questions Ads, and is broad enough to allow for promoting main site and meta content specific to each community.

With that being said, the revised guidance/goals for the initiative reads:

- **Community Promotion Ads** (all non-SO sites)
  The goal of this initiative is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.
- **Open Source Ads** (SO only)
  The goal of this initiative is to promote advertisements **soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code**. This is not intended as a general purpose ad for consumer products which just happen to be open source. It's for finding programmers who will help contribute code or other programmery things (documentation, code review, bug fixes, etc.).
- **"Hot Network Questions"<sup>1</sup> Ads** (all sites)
  This initiative has an added goal of providing your community with an opportunity to showcase exemplary questions from your main site, as well as frequently-linked-to guides from your Meta site. While the latter makes sense to be shown solely on this site, the former can be shown all across the network. These should avoid hot button topics, and instead focus more on evergreen questions that show what your community’s all about.

To clarify, and at the risk of repeating myself, all of these initiatives would be bundled into a single post, and the above guidance is a template split up only so it's easier to understand what bits replace the currently existing initiatives.

### Further Guidelines

As is mentioned in [the roadmap post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/23/the-loop-our-community-public-platform-roadmap-for-q2-2021/), as well as [my answer from a month ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362656/208518), one of the reasons for reworking this initiative is the unmaintained old code that the current format relies on. Additionally, while having these ads be generated dynamically over the course of the year they run based on their fluctuating score is nice, it also produces overhead in terms of making sure the ads are compliant with our guidelines. The revised format will instead rely on an open collection period, at the end of which a "snapshot" of the ads that make the cut will be collected so they're run during the next year. We're proposing a single "submission season" at the beginning of the year, that runs for 1 month across all the sites where the initiative is run, after which all the posts with a minimum score of 6 will be selected and run for the coming year.

Obviously, all proposed ads need to abide by [our Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). Additionally, given we're trying to align this initiative with our Ad Team's regular ad campaigns' structure, [our ad creative guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/guidelines) will also generally apply (note that the first 2 bullet points on the “Tracking” section do not apply, and a lot of the guidelines surrounding claims, comparisons, proof, etc., while still applicable, may not be particularly relevant for this initiative). Finally, ads can not be promoting products nor soliciting programmer time or resources for: knowledge sharing or collaboration tools for technologists, or for sites where ad buyers are primarily targeting technologists.

### Formatting bits

When the collection posts go out, they'll provide a detailed list of requirements surrounding file formatting names, sizes, clickthrough URLs, etc. For now, the two new bits worth highlighting are:

- Whereas the current initiatives only allow for right sidebar ads (300x250), **the new initiative will also allow users to submit banner ads (728x90)**. We recognize that not all sites currently have banner ads, so it's possible that if the inventory to be displayed on a given site is too low, we'd need to put measures in place to ensure users aren't getting exposed to the same ad(s) over and over again.
- Whereas ads submitted in the current initiatives will only be displayed on the site where they're submitted (so, the MSO post will collect ads to display on SO, for instance), **the new initiative will allow users to specify whether the ad should be displayed on the same site (mimicking the Community Promotion and Open Source Ads format), on all other sites (mimicking the Hot Network Questions Ads format), or on a subset of other sites (say, on all the tech sites)**. This'll also mean the CM team and the communities will need to work closely when defining their target audiences, to ensure the ads are relevant and not disruptive to the communities where they're being displayed.

### Reporting

One of the benefits of revising this initiative, as I'd explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362656/208518), would be that we'd be able to provide the communities with more detailed reporting of how your ads are performing. As I worked with our Ads team in this initiative, a few things came up as the bare minimum of what we can report back on:

- Metrics:

  - Impressions
  - Clicks
  - CTR
- Dimensions:

  - Date
  - Site
  - Line Item (Type of campaign, e.g.: "Hot Network Questions,"<sup>1</sup> Open Source, Community Promotion)
  - Creative

**We'd like to hear from you on whether there are any other things you'd like to see reported**, bearing in mind that we can't promise to publicly share any that could potentially be used to reveal trade secrets to competitors.

### Trial

Since we're approaching the middle of the year, we thought running a trial through the end of 2021 might be appropriate. Last year there was a low level of engagement on many of the sites where I posted these, so given that we're running a trial on the 34 sites where at least one ad made it to the minimum score of 6 in 2020:

- [Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4934/32458)
- [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2655/100275)
- [Apple](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4006/120123)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19615/306823)
- [Biology](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4212/15165)
- [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1088/24870)
- [Blender](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2809/13499)
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5028/15268)
- [Christianity](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7086/20468)
- [Code Golf & Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23537/38734)
- [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10697/69261)
- [Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6160/72321)
- [Cryptography](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1531/23602)
- [Data Science](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2576/8879)
- [English Language and Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15038/115443)
- [Ethereum](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/678/12)
- [Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15880/41070)
- [GIS](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5287/49787)
- [Information Security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3439/71390)
- [Mathematica](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2616/27404)
- [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33720/227543)
- [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5421/9208)
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4772/20055)
- [Music: Practice & Theory](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3739/19682)
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13630/27856)
- [Role-playing Games](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11612/22114)
- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13395/6365)
- [Skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4750/25620)
- [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408437/1328704)
- [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8792/75272)
- [Unix and Linux](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5795/93139)
- [WordPress](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4749/69863)
- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8330/8555)
- [Writing](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419/13317)

**In June I'll post a collection question with the guidance defined above for these sites, where the communities will be able to post proposed ads that fall under the Community Promotion Ads (or Open Source Ads on SO) guidance, and also the guidance for the bit of the initiative that replaces of the now defunct "HNQ" ads — all under a single collection question.**

The list of sites above constitutes a good mix of topics, sizes, and levels of engagement with the initiative in 2020, so we're hoping they'll be able to give us a decent overview of how the network as a whole would engage with the proposed new initiative.

Once that's over, we'd provide the aforementioned report on how the ads did, and will also be looking at general engagement with the initiative as a whole. Additionally, given the new proposed targeting possibilities, we'll also be looking at the amount of ads getting reported since there's a possibility that some of the "Hot Network Questions"<sup>1</sup> ads may actually turn out to be somewhat disruptive due to their off-topic-ness. Based on what we see, we'll determine next steps — though assuming all goes well, we can start doing these on an annual basis, and adjust if there's a call for a faster rotation of ads. Stack Overflow's may be refreshed twice a year, as has been customary. Depending on the level of engagement we see, we'll then decide on whether to expand these to more sites, and potentially revise the current policy of only doing this on non-beta sites.

### Conclusion

**If you have questions, comments, or concerns, please leave them as an answer below. Please see the section on reporting above, and leave feedback if there's stuff you'd like to see reporting on and is not listed there.** I hope I can address most of it, but can't make any promises, as usual. **Please leave any feedback by May 31st.**

That's prolly plenty of words for now. I hope that you find value in this initiative, and am looking forward to (manually) posting all of these in the coming month!

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm referring to these as Hot Network Questions throughout the post, but once we roll this out we may start calling them something else since... well, given the nature of the new initiative, we won't really be looking for "hot" posts. They're more like "popular" or "frequently asked" questions, really.

Comment: Hmmm, [I wonder what that non-compete clause is about...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394409/open-source-advertising-1h-2020/394417#394417)

Comment: Are community ads only supported on non-beta sites? I didn't look through the complete list of sites, but most of the ones that made the list looked to be either graduates or in the limbo world between graduation and beta.

Comment: We've only done Community Promotion Ads for non-Beta sites in the past, correct, @hazzey

Comment: "They're more like "popular" or "frequently asked" questions, really." With frequently-asked, I think about questions which have lots of duplicates. However, that has nothing to do with the current HNQ system.

Comment: Could you summarize what this effectively changes in the short term for the 34 sites you've listed?

Comment: The part of this that'll replace the HNQ won't have anything to do with the HNQ system either, @Mast — all of these will be manually curated, rather than algorithmically selected. And I said "popular" because it will allow folks to highlight exemplary questions, and "frequently asked" because it can be used to highlight Meta guidance type of questions that may be useful for new users.

Comment: These sites will have a collection post in June to test this new model, in which they'll be able to submit proposed ads that align with the above guidance: stuff that falls under what Community Promotion Ads would have been, as well as stuff that falls under the new guidance that aims to replace the now-defunct HNQ ads — all under a single post/initiative. Is that not clear in the post itself, @Mast?

Comment: IMO it wasn't entirely clear, no. It looks like there's a lot of potential with this potential, but we'll have to figure out the details of how it works and what works best somewhere in the next month it seems.

Comment: I agree with @Mast -- it's not clear what, if anything, is different on the upcoming collection round as compared to previous years. It sounds like you're changing the code internally but not doing *that* much to how it looks like to the site users. If there are significant changes, it would be good to see them listed explicitly.

Comment: Does my edit make it any clearer, @E.P. and Mast? I thought it was already clear given the "To clarify, and at the risk of repeating myself..." bit, but reiterated once again :P

Comment: Looks a little clearer at least, but we'll patiently wait for the June post to find out.

Comment: Can someone please explain @ArtOfCode's comment to me like I'm 5 years old?  I didn't get it :-)

Comment: @cs95 - Last time the Open Source ads were run, the top-voted ad was for Codidact, which is an open-source Q&A platform. SE apparently didn't like that a project that could be considered a competitor was advertising for free on their site, and so created a new rule to prevent it.

Comment: "Finally, ads can not be promoting products or soliciting programmer time or resources for knowledge sharing projects that are competitive to Stack Overflow, broadly construed." -- is that Stack Overflow the *site*, or Stack Overflow the *company*? Are ads promoting non-programming, off-network knowledge sharing allowed or not?

Comment: @tpg2114 sometimes... there's not that much difference. I kinda think they mean both competing projects, and competing sites under the projects.  I don't particularly see the potential for say, ads for codidact's power users site turning up on super user

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's my interpretation also -- but it would be important to have clear marching orders on it since Physics in the past iterations has run ads for a non-programming, off-network Physics knowledge site that is a direct competitor (not Codadict-based). So it will come up, and we'll need to know what to do given it's a touchy subject anyway... knowing what we need to do before it happens will at least head off some issues.

Comment: I think my most recent edit addresses your question, right, @tpg2114?

Comment: Does "[...] or for sites where ad buyers are targeting technologists" mean that ads for other sites on the network (SO etc.) are now forbidden?

Comment: @JNat I think it does -- I will follow up privately if not. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Comment: @JNat Some sites had community ads to other stackexchange sites, e.g. tex.se had an ad for writing.se. However some stackexchange communities (like SO) also show commercial ads targeting technologists (whatever that means). Can communities still show ads to such sites?

Comment: Those restrictions don't apply to intra-network advertising, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz — if I'm reading you right, I think that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Can you explain how "*for knowledge sharing or collaboration tools for technologists, or for sites where ad buyers are targeting technologists*" actually differs from "*for knowledge sharing projects that are competitive to Stack Overflow, broadly construed*"? I can't wrap my head around any material differences here; Stack Overflow is largely a competitor specifically to "collaboration tools for technologists", is it not?

Comment: The current wording removed the "broadly construed" bit, which was a bit vague and [scary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364763/208518). It also cleared some of the ambiguity around SO vs SE expressed in the comments here, @zcoop98 — so, to answer your question, the rewording wasn't meant to be a material one that changed the intention behind that "clause." The main difference is the "for technologists" bit, which clarifies the target audience of the types of products and communities that would be disqualified from being advertised under this program. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JNat It does make it a bit clearer, thanks for clarifying! I appreciate it :)

Comment: The ads are [**not** up](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34082/i-am-seeing-community-promotion-ads-from-the-old-2020-proposal) on math.se!

Comment: With 2021 behind us, are the stats/metrics going to be published somewhere?

Comment: They are, indeed, @MathieuGuindon — still working on that, but should be able to share those in the coming weeks.

Comment: "in the coming weeks" ...6-8, I guess 

Comment: Any update on this program?

Comment: Mid/end of August (i.e. the upper end of 6-8 _months_), and still nothing for 2022, let alone anything about how 2021 went. What happened to this project? Dead or forgotten?

Comment: Apologies for the complete silence on this one. I don't have any updates, but can reassure folks that the project has _not_ been forgotten. Unfortunately, other higher-priority issues have precluded me from being able to report back on this one, but doing so is still on my backlog.

Comment: Are community ads running in 2022 or 2023?

Comment: This campaign from 2021 is still running, as far as I'm aware. I'm hoping to have meaningful updates in the first quarter of 2023, but that's dependent on several factors so not a hard commitment unfortunately, @JohnyWhy

Comment: @JNat I viewed SO ad info pages, and it seems there are no low-cost ad options, only hundreds or thousands of dollars per ad, correct?

Comment: As far as you're aware? Don't Community Ads have a responsible person? Might it be helpful to have a permanent landing page dedicated to community ads to inform people  how it works and when the next cycle starts, instead of just blindly randomly searching and hoping to find a new post about the next ad cycle?

Comment: I'm not sure what our paid ad options are, @JohnyWhy, as that falls way outside my purview. As you may have gathered from this post and the fact that I don't have updates, though, we're currently still assessing next steps for this program — I'll keep your suggestion in mind, though, since it may be appropriate depending on what the program ends up looking like.

Comment: @JNat Community Ads have been a thing for over 10 years. Seems to be in flux every year, but seems it usually ends up happening. After 10+ years, maybe it's time for SO to make to make a commitment? It seems unfair to the community to be iffy about what services SO offers -- especially ten years on.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "seems to be in flux every year" @JohnyWhy. The program has been an ongoing steady feature for 10+ years, as you noted. Until this post we're commenting under went live, Community Promotion/Open Source Ads _were_ a steady commitment from SO. As the post and links therein note, however, a number of factors led to us having to make changes, which in turn led to the place we're in now — like I said, we're assessing next steps.

Comment: @JNat My bad. Maybe just seems in flux for 2021, 2022, 2023. I yesterday learned about the initiative. I'm interested in Open Source ads. Are they also unsure to continue?

Comment: I wouldn't say they're unsure to continue, @JohnyWhy, just that we're unsure what the next steps are as of yet. More updates when we have a clear path forward.

Answer (score 50):

> Finally, ads can not be promoting products or soliciting programmer time or resources for knowledge sharing projects that are competitive to Stack Overflow, broadly construed.

- So, this clause was created just to eliminate [those](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394417/479251) [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394474/479251), right?
- The "broadly construed" phrase in itself is frightening, and probably useless. Otherwise, I could easily spot many of the candidates which are for "sharing knowledge".
- Not sure to understand this clause. If the projects concerned are open-source, then Stack Overflow, as anyone else, will be able to reap the produced result, right?

I have not been and don't want to be involved in the debates that have stormed meta months ago, and initiated those linked projects above.

I think Stack Overflow as a company can and should prove itself not afraid of the community and to be above those pesky clauses and fights.

SO and the programming community itself could seriously benefit of some fresh point of view. And frankly, the chance of these becoming actual competitors of Stack Overflow are minuscule.

The result is just more stirring of what should have been settled. I was not involved, now I'm disappointed; I thought this was over.

Rise above this and let them be present (provided they meet the usual same criteria as the others, of course).

## TL/DR:

There is nothing dangerous for SO/SE here. By adding this clause, it's just stirring old disturbances that should have been buried. Both SO and the community would benefit from having diversity in the knowledge sharing ecosystem. You should remove this clause, and treat all candidates the same, regardless on how "broadly construed" they seem to compete with Stack Overflow.

Comment: I wonder if Wikibooks is a competitor.

Comment: or the mdn or any github issue

Comment: I made an edit to the language around the portion of text you're quoting so it's clearer and less ambiguous. I understand how the previous wording could lead to a reading of the situation such as the one you're presenting, but I think this revised wording clarifies what we're disallowing and why we're doing it.

Answer (score 45):

Are banner ads worth the trouble?

I almost didn't post this because I'm not really sure about this, but my initial impression is that banner ads add far more complications than they might be worth. You increase the amount of effort and knowledge necessary to post ads as people now need to be able to provide different ad formats and you also require them to understand the consequences of the ad format choices on whatever algorithm you have that selects to display ads. If this isn't done carefully, it also has the potential to annoy people because banner ads are more intrusive than sidebar ads. And most established users are above the reputation threshold where banner ads are shown, so the most active users won't ever see these banner ads.

Including banner ads feels like an unnecessary complication to me at this point. I think it would be safer to start this with sidebar ads only, and only go for banner ads if you're really sure there is a significant benefit there.

Comment: No, the regular community ads don't get seen enough. I am 100% in favor of the addition of banner ads.

Comment: Folks don't _need_ to be able to provide different ad formats; they _can_. Does the question convey that you'd need to submit an ad in both formats? If so, lemme know so I can clarify. I do understand the potential for disruption you mention, though, which is why I mention looking at reported ads, etc. Furthermore, we can all decide that we only wanna allow banner ads for same-site advertising, rather than random off-topic ads on other sites — as in, maybe Math can advertise a Meta.Math FAQ post in a banner, but Cooking can't have a banner ad for a popular question show on SO.

Comment: These can be worked into the guidelines if y'all feel it'd be preferable (now if we wanna prevent disruption, or after the trial if we wanna test and find them disruptive after all).

Comment: I did not see a single ad on the SO long, long ago.

Comment: Fortunately, they do not use anti-ad-blocking measures. Hopefully they will continue to do that.

Comment: @peterh well, other than using non-ad space for teams ads, such as banners and colorful boxes in the nav menu.

Answer (score 36):

> The revised format will instead rely on an open collection period, at the end of which a "snapshot" of the ads that make the cut will be collected so they're run during the next year. We're proposing **a single "submission season"** at the beginning of the year, that runs for 1 month across all the sites where the initiative is run, after which all the posts with a minimum score of 6 will be selected and run for the coming year.

That sounds extremely draconian and pretty close to a no-go for me. Community Ads evolve slowly, true, but making them be completely frozen in time for a year at a time does not allow for any flexibility at all as the conversation around them evolves, and it makes it unavailable to new users, who must wait for an average of six months before being able to propose one. (If you're looking for internal KPIs, this fails the "being friendly and welcoming to newcomers" checkbox, in a bad way.)

With this in mind:

> having these ads be generated dynamically over the course of the year they run based on their fluctuating score is nice

I think "nice" is an understatement here. I would describe it more as a key feature of the mechanism.

> it also produces overhead in terms of making sure the ads are compliant with our guidelines

That's fair. But what kind of overhead is this? Are they vetted by humans? Is it an automated process?

If continuous approval is not feasible, I would suggest changing the single "submission season" to a quarterly (ideally monthly?) sign-up process: set up a single thread per year, and then at the end of each quarter, any ads that have broken past the 6-vote threshold (and any that have been edited) go through any required vetting and then get added to the roster. This allows further ads to be vetted as required, without needing to re-vet any already-approved ones.

(And if the time requirements for this vetting are too much, I would submit that this implies that you do not actually have the resources to vet the ads that the communities require.)

Comment: How about one post per year, that is reviewed quarterly to see if any new ads have gotten six votes? I'm also concerned about smaller sites that might have trouble getting to 6 votes. These are the sites that arguably need the most promotion.

Comment: I did say "though assuming all goes well, we can start doing these on an annual basis, **and adjust if there's a call for a faster rotation of ads.**" (with highlight added here) So I do recognize the downsides of have a "snapshot" of the ads, rather than a dynamically generated pool of ads to draw from.

Comment: @LShaver Yes, that was the idea -- it was implicit and should've been explicit, I guess.

Comment: @JNat That got lost in the sea of text. I think there's definitely a need for faster add-in than once a year. For one thing, if low engagement is already a problem, forcing communities to vote within one month or miss the bus is only going to exacerbate it.

Comment: @JNat This is close enough to the answer that I was going to write that I'll comment here. `"We're proposing a single "submission season" at the beginning of the year, that runs for 1 month across all the sites where the initiative is run, .."` - Could we start Nov. 15th and run for 6 weeks, with a 'Staff approval' made within the first week of a quarter? That allows the infrequently visited child-metas to accumulate enough votes and for the Community AD to run for an extra few weeks (rather than vote a month, wait a month); it also allows complaints, suggestions, even Flags to improve the AD.

Comment: @Rob Honestly, I'd rather avoid the (relatively quiet) December season for this (personally)... I think it'd be better overall to move away from the January timeline and look at running these, say, starting in February or March or whenever makes sense for user activity levels. :)

Comment: @Catija I don't oppose Feb/Mar but if this answer gets enough votes, and quarterly submissions are approved, we still have a start 3 months before Feb/Mar; which would be Nov 1 / Dec 1, where 3 months later is Feb 1 / Mar 1 - so your comment *seems* to propose no change or 2 weeks earlier than my comment - if this answer is approved.

Comment: @JNat I second that community ads can't work very well if we have only one month to submit them and eleven months to display them. In the model we've had until now, we could create new ads as things became relevant, and we could downvote ads out of the rotation if problems came up. You're taking a model that works well for enterprise customers and requiring ordinary communities to operate with it, and ... that doesn't work so well for us. Context may come up in our community that entirely fades from relevance by the time the next year rolls around. Can we start with six months tops instead?

Comment: We _are_ starting with a 6 month period, @doppelgreener :) I wrote: "Since we're approaching the middle of the year, we thought running a trial through the end of 2021 might be appropriate." I know I also mention something about a yearly rotation in the post, but that's not because of some model we use for enterprise costumers, just me using the yearly rotation we currently do for Community Promotion Ads as a baseline. But as I mention multiple times in the post, we can always adjust depending on the trial :)

Comment: That's a relief! Thank you.

Comment: Some sites (here I represent tex.sx) have posted community ads to announce conferences or other special events.  Limiting posting to January effectively prevents this practice as the timing does not mesh with the requirementss of the organizers.  And the delay this year has already caused a number of relevant deadlines to be missed.  (And it was highly embarrassing yesterday to see an announcement for a conference that took place last August.)

Comment: @JNat (cont'd from [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13630/community-ads-for-2021#comment51818_13630)) to clarify -- the questions in this post (what kind of overhead is this? Are they vetted by humans? Is it an automated process?) remain unanswered. This makes it very hard to propose alternatives that meet the community needs and the development realities half-way. So for now our only option is to continue to point out the places where the loss of value occurs as they crop up.

Comment: The overhead I was referring to there, @E.P., was the fact that the Ad Ops team would need to be constantly monitoring the Meta posts to check for new ads being displayed under the old system. Like I mentioned, the code it uses is unmaintained, and it does not serve the ads as per the same system the rest of the ads get served network-wide. While all other ads are vetted by staff individually and manually, these weren't. The old system did not allow for a reasonable way for the Ad Ops team (or the Community Team) to vet what ads are being displayed on our sites.

Comment: @JNat Thanks for the reply. If I understand your answer correctly, there is no technical (as opposed to organizational) barrier to scheduling such a process once a month? (particularly given that the *ongoing* vetting likely represents a fraction of the load in the initial 'submission season' and that ads that are already running do not need to be re-vetted.)

Comment: There is no technical barrier, no, @E.P. — but doing this once a month creates overhead elsewhere, since it'd require me posting ad collection posts on all eligible sites once a month, manually... unless we automate it. (You may see where I'm going next, but...) This is why we're running a trial, and will then decide on how frequently these should be posted, and based on that also have reason to justify automating some bits that need automating.

Comment: @JNat Why would it require posting new threads every month? Why not just use the same threads (i.e. one thread per year) as their answers accumulate votes, detect which answers have make it over the 6-vote threshold, and queue those for manual vetting once a month?

Comment: A new post ensures that the posts that make it past the score threshold are still relevant for the period in question, rather than us showing the same ads over and over again just because they got up to a score of 6 a year ago (or whatever). That being said, that's just how I'm thinking about it at a high-level right now, @E.P.; could be that we implement it in some other way when the time comes, after the trial.

Comment: @JNat I thought that was why the rotation was refreshed every year. (For time-limited posts answers can simply be deleted.) Are there strong indications that the current one-year rotation period is too long, and a large fraction of adverts is becoming obsolete before the rotation? Note also that the current stated plan (single submission season, then ads get locked in for a full year) also suffers from that precise same problem.

Comment: Seriously, it sounds like you have made a decision (for whatever reasons) and now you are just looking for ways to rationalize it ex post facto (leading to the long stack of increasingly-implausible justifications). Please reconsider.

Comment: You're attributing some of my comments about the new system to the old one, and vice-versa, @E.P. — I dunno that I can clarify stuff any more at this point, short of repeating myself.

Answer (score 21):

> - **"Hot Network Questions"<sup>1</sup> Ads** (all sites)
>
> This initiative has an added goal of providing your community with an opportunity to showcase exemplary questions from your main site

This reminds me of the [Tour](/tour) which features one example question (which one can be [selected by ♦ moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163947/295232)). Would it make sense to integrate those features? Will ♦ moderators be able to showcase/unshowcase specific questions?

Comment: The tour page itself is a bit scope-creepy for this project, especially during the trial. May be a reasonable thing to include in next steps, depending on how the test goes, though ^_^

Comment: I think it is essential to the succes of HNQ ads, that these questions are really exemplar questions of that community. Therefore I don't think we should rely on metrics to decide which questions should be showcased, but on human judgement. Whether that is done manually by CM/Staff (let each site pick X questions to be eligible for ads) or have some Mod tooling to more frequently rotate questions is a detail that could be worked out later.

Comment: Oh, I'm in agreement with regards to these needing to be manually curated rather than algorithmically picked — that's why my calling them "HNQ" is footnoted, since they actually are meant to replace those and won't be "hot" any more. Whether the tour page gets added functionality or somehow worked on as a part of this project is what I meant is scope-creepy for the moment.

Comment: eh... i dunno if i trust moderators to choose questions that are actually on topic rather than just interesting enough to avoid closure.

Comment: @KevinB (and others) Not moderators - people voting on meta. If I understand the project, the "hot" questions would get proposed in the same manner as the ads do now - six upvotes on meta, the community has judged it to be a good one to include. This is not like the tour, which is decided by mods, it's like the community ads/open source ads we've had. Also, many sites have gone through a meta discussion process to decide what should be the featured question on the tour... so it's not even just mods deciding then.

Comment: That is correct, @Catija

Comment: Right, i was referring to this part of the answer, *"Will ♦ moderators be able to showcase/unshowcase specific questions"*. I could see veto power existing

Comment: I read that as being specific to the broader discussion around the tour page, @KevinB. But if it is about this initiative specifically, then I didn't foresee including a veto power for mods on this, no.

Answer (score 16):

> - **Community Promotion Ads** (all non-SO sites)
>   The goal of this initiative is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

> The revised format will instead rely on an open collection period, at the end of which a "snapshot" of the ads that make the cut will be collected so they're run during the next year. We're proposing a single "submission season" at the beginning of the year, that runs for 1 month across all the sites where the initiative is run, after which all the posts with a minimum score of 6 will be selected and run for the coming year.

I regularly use community ads for time-bound events, launching the new ad when the event is announced or begins, and deleting the ad when the event ends. The ads have been well-received by the community. For example, one such ad currently has the second-highest number of clicks per day for the community in question.

Examples of such time-bound uses (**dear reader: feel free to add to this list!**):

- [APL Problem Solving Competition 2021](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18915/43319) (Code Golf)
- [Dyalog APL Seeds 2021](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20826/43319) (Code Golf)
- [Stay home, save lives](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5306/3073) (Mi Yodeya)
- [TUG 19](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8075) (TEX, see edit history)
- [Biology moderator election 2019](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3904/48820), [2017](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3600/16866) (Biology)
- [WHO COVID-19](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4071/13215) (Biology)

This new system seems to prevent this usage. **Please confirm that you want to get rid of my usage.**

Comment: I can confirm that the use case you're mentioning wouldn't be possible any more, yes. Wouldn't say that "want to get rid of [it]" is an accurate description of the situation here, though ;P

Comment: @JNat Why not? You may not have been aware of this implication before, but now that you are, please consider it, and make a concious decision about wanting to get rid of it or not. If you don't want to get rid of it, you've got to change your plans!

Comment: I wasn't necessarily aware of that being a _common_ use case (if you have some examples, links would be appreciated). And while the proposed approach for the trial does indeed make that use case impossible, depending on its success and how frequently we end up doing and refreshing these, it may become possible again in the future.

Comment: @JNat I've added links to two examples.

Comment: @JNat Btw, if Stack Exchange had asked the community *before* deciding on drastic changes like this, you could have known in advance.

Comment: We have unmaintained code that needs to go, which is what prompted this project — getting rid of that code _needs_ to happen. Doing so entails getting rid of the dynamically generated pool of ads, unfortunately. We're doing a trial of a new lightweight approach (code-wise), and will iterate on it — if there's enough engagement with the new format, we'll see what can/should be modified, both in terms of guidelines, etc. (meaning faster refreshes, or allowing for special use cases like yours), and potentially in terms of more dev work. So the "before deciding" you mention is now, on this post.

Comment: There might be other site specific events going on at specific times - Site anniversaries and other special events  come to mind. It seems something that would add to how useful this is - but probably a pain to get working 'after the fact' - whether the means to do so is technical or a process to get someone adding and removing these ads manually

Comment: @JNat I've added two more. With the new system, these two, potentially life-saving, ads might have had to wait for months…

Comment: @JNat Will edits to the ads be possible? This system was used e.g. for https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8075 to avoid an ad for a conference to become obsolete.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've added yours to the list.

Comment: To be fair, @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, editing ads _while_ they're being served wasn't really a feature of the current implementation of Community Promotion Ads — in fact, doing so was actually discouraged.

Comment: @JNat but does it work?

Comment: @Pureferret Yes.

Answer (score 6):

#### Request for clarification about the ad sizes:

> "Whereas the current initiatives only allow for right sidebar ads (300x250), **the new initiative will also allow users to submit banner ads (728x90)**"

The "current" rule that was listed in your (JNat's) post on all of the non-beta sites for the 2020 community ads says:

> "The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI."

which means that (600 x 500) is okay too. On [Chem.SE](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4653/27342) 100% of the 10 ads used the (600 x 500) size, and 7 out of 8 ads on [Phys.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12737/134583) did.

I suppose that the ads that actually get shown on the right-side of the screen, end up only being (300 x 250) anyway, but it's useful to be able to show them as (600 x 500) when running these ads for election in Meta. Is it correct that the (600 x 500) option was only for running the ads for election in Meta (not for the actual ads as they appear anywhere) and that we would still have the option to post them in (600 x 500) format when running them for election?

Comment: That's a good point. Technically this would be possible, but it would add a layer of complexity to the process of setting these ads up. So for the purposes of the trial we've decided to only allow 300x250 and 728x90 banners. We'll see how this goes after that, and will consider including this possibility at the first evaluation of this project.

Comment: @JNat If the 600x500 doubled-for-Retina format gets ruled out it will feel rather antagonistic for no good reason. As mentioned in this answer, we have a large catalog in the large format. It would be very nice to be able to reuse it without being forced to re-sample multiple ads, particularly if there is no strong reason for forcing the change.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @JNat, I'm an alpha tester of the new Markdown/rich-text Stacks editor and while this answer seemed to turn out properly yesterday when I drafted the answer, something seems to have messed up afterwards (i.e. extra `\\` escape characters) which you fixed just now.

Comment: You make a good point about the re-sampling of the existing catalogue, @E.P. — I checked with the Ads team, and we'd be willing to allow for the higher density ads as usual for the trial, even if at the risk of incurring in some errors :) We can always adjust later, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

I am super excited about my community coming out of beta -- predominantly because of the community ads.

I need to reach out to organizers, groups, and businesses and tell them what is happening so that they can begin designing their ads.

Trouble is, I don't know what specific dimensions to tell them to prepare and I don't necessarily know if our "submission season" will be the month of January.

Can you clarify what media is needed for submission and what timeline is for newly matured sites?

This was [my last faux-attempt](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/386/12352), but it looks like things have changed slightly since then.

Answer (score 1):

> and even some other types of ads that Nicolas has experimented with in the International SOs (like [this](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8353/23291), or ads that link to Meta posts like [this](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7020/181239)).

I find the examples very interesting, but I do have 1 significant problem: I don't speak Russian. For folks who don't speak Portuguese nor Russian they're left without a significant example of the *"other types of ads"*.

Comment: Chrome has a tool that will translate the page for you, I'm sure that other browsers do, too - I can see that the examples are ads that link to meta posts that help users understand how to use the site. The images are described in text that can be (relatively) easily translated. :)

Comment: @Catija This post was meant as a well humored comment/observation not as a critique. (I can read one of the example threads and find it really funny in several ways).