# Please show the date of the last public action of an account in the profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, last-activity

After the rather controversial decision of removing the last seen information, I would like to request having a "last action" field.

While discussing on Meta Stack Overflow, [ayhan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2285236/ayhan) came up with what I think is a [really good idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410617/bring-the-last-seen-field-back-on-profile-page-please/410643?noredirect=1#comment859192_410643):

> [...] I personally wouldn't mind a "last active" field which refers to my last public action (a post, a comment, a revision...)

I believe it to be a very good compromise because the last action a user has made is already public. One could open a profile, and rummage through posts, comments, votes, and see the last action, but it would take time.

So having it readily available would both save time for people moderating posts as well as respect the privacy concern of the users happy with the field disappearing.

To reiterate: this is not a request to add information that is not already available, simply to save time for the humans who use that information in the course of their moderation activities.

Comment: This information is already provided [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/243821/f%c3%a9lix-gagnon-grenier?tab=activity&sort=all)

Comment: @Ramhound Considering that the idea here is to save time, while this is in the right direction, it's still not as readily available as the field being visible in the main landing page profile. Still, one could probably use that to parse some kind of user script of last activity, I guess.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368321/282094)

Comment: @Rob do you think I should have posted this as an answer over there?

Comment: Felix, Often the last sentence will say: "Please share your feedback and questions on this post.", or [this example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556/282094): "If you have questions, comments, or concerns, please leave them as an answer below. Please see the section on reporting above, and leave feedback if there's stuff you'd like to see reporting on and is not listed there. I hope I can address most of it, but can't make any promises, as usual. Please leave any feedback by May 31st.". - In that case Aaron omitted this info, but has received 50 Feedbacks. :)

Comment: It would also be helpful to include very specific non-action events - like if a user viewed *their own question*, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Finding out when a user was last active on the site, excluding passively reading and voting, takes two additional clicks to get to the profile's Activity page and then select "All Actions" (https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/243821/f%c3%a9lix-gagnon-grenier?tab=activity)

Step one: click on someone's profile

> [image: screenshot of the first click to open Felix's profile]

Step two: select their "Activity" tab:

> [image: screenshot of selecting Felix's activity tab]

Step three: select the "All Actions" tab on the activity tab:

> [image: screenshot of Felix's "All Actions" list]

Then look at the timestamp of the last action.

I don't see much need to summarize that activity in another spot. The solution is not to change the way the information is presented; it is to give us control over how much of our activity is public. I should be able to choose to keep my activity private or not without affecting someone else's privacy choices. That way people who value keeping their activity private over others being able to easily tell that they are still engaged with the site can do so.

Trying to find ways to restore the "last seen" statistic in some other form instead of pushing for improvements that will address the privacy concerns some users have expressed is in my opinion a wasted opportunity.

Comment: Cool, it's clearer. Ok, I think I understand, but what do you mean with giving control? For instance, do you mean that someone would be able to prevent others from knowing they posted an answer, or commented? or simply an opt-in to remove the last seen information?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I mean it should be your choice whether someone can see your activity on the site or not. Maybe I don't want everyone to know I'm in the review queue closing their questions :) and maybe you don't care and would rather have people know when you're active so they can ping you in chat. Why should my preference be forced on you?

Comment: Ok, if this is hidden behind two clicks, why not show it immediately in the profile? Remember that this is (very similar to) something we had before, not a new feature.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Because I think if we're going to have all this drama because someone thought "last seen" was creepy and removed it, we should not waste the community's engagement on the issue and instead actually take a step forward instead of keeping the same bad statistic in a different form. You can [put lipstick on a pig](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lipstick+on+a+pig), but that doesn't change that it is still a pig.