# Cardano is leaving Beta

Tags: discussion, beta-sites, announcements, site-lifecycle

Congratulations to the community on [Cardano](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/)! They have officially left Public Beta as of today.

In December, we had [59 sites on the Stack Exchange Network shed their Beta labels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta). We also announced that [Community Managers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-is-on-the-community-management-team-and-what-does-it-do) now have the ability to remove sites from Public Beta once they meet the criteria, without needing a developer. The current criteria for losing the Beta label are:

- The site needs to be in Beta for at least six months
- The site needs to have at least 1000 open questions
- At least 70% of the questions on the site need to have at least one upvoted answer

Similar to the sites that left Beta in December, Cardano will:

- have the word “Beta” removed from the banner at the top of the site
- be moved to the [“Launched” sites list](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched) on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/), which will also remove the Area 51 information box from the right sidebar of the site
- retain the artificially-lowered reputation thresholds for site privileges, so those thresholds will stay the same as in Beta
- have their full-site moderator elections scheduled in the future (as we mentioned in December, we'll start scheduling full-site elections in the spring)
- be eligible for community ads ([we'll be talking about that more in the near future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364556/the-future-of-community-promotion-open-source-and-hot-network-questions-ads))

Congratulations again to the Cardano community and their moderator team on this milestone!

Comment: Excuse me if I'm missing something, but why is this here and not Cardano's per-site meta?

Comment: @bobble We worked with the Cardano mods on the timing so they knew when the Beta label would be removed. They'll be making a post on their Meta. I know in the past we haven't announced individual sites leaving Beta on MSE, but since we did announce the 29 sites that left Beta in 2019 and the 59 sites that left Beta in December it felt right to start sharing when individual sites leave Beta here too.

Comment: [Related answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta/374111#374111) from the second reference.

Comment: [related post on cardano meta](https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/cardano-is-leaving-beta)

Comment: So the three bullets listed are now the *permanent* criteria for leaving beta? Sites are no longer required to achieve a routine 10 questions per day and 90% answer rate, as before?

Comment: Four years ago: [Let's break up with "Graduation" and remove a bunch of "Beta" labels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303727/lets-break-up-with-graduation-and-remove-a-bunch-of-beta-labels)

Comment: Remove the Beta label, allow users to elect their moderators but these site still look like country cousins. These sites *appear* to be 2nd class communities because they ALL look identical to one another. Some of these ex-Beta sites have been waiting years for a theme. They need to have an identity, they need to be easily identifiable, they deserve a bit of TLC. A graduation without the ceremony is hugely disappointing.